# Scala how to print contents of a class's returned string and not Class@3c8bdd5b

Tags: scala, class, println

Is there an easy way to print the contents of what is returned from a new class object? I am testing with Fun Suite.  Please see example below:

```
test("test") {
val contentString = new TestClass("test")
println("CONTENT IS: " + contentString)
}
```

The output is "CONTENT IS: TestClass@3c8bdd5b" and I would like to see "CONTENT IS: actual string content"

Thanks

Comment: Did you define TestClass yourself?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `toString` method. If you defined the class, you can do it inside the class definition as usual, e.g.:

```
 class TestClass(val x: String){
   override def toString = x
 }
```

otherwise, you can extend the `TestClass` or create an anonymous class overriding the `toString` method, e.g.:

```
 class TestClass(val x: String){
 }

 val z = new TestClass("hello world"){
     override def toString = x
   }   // this will show " z: TestClass = hello world " in the REPL
```

Answer (score 1):

You should override toString method of your TestClass.

Another possible solution use "case classes" that provides toString implementation.